# Cannot read property 'getRequest' of undefined - Relay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relay

I am trying to make my 1st Relay query. I did `npm run relay` and `npm run build`. Everything works well, but in console I am getting error:
[image]

Does anybody know what may cause this error?

Update.

> Table.js (component where I want make query)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { graphql, QueryRenderer } from 'react-relay';

const environment = import('../../environment.js');

class Table extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

        <QueryRenderer
            environment={environment}
            query={graphql`
                query TableQuery {
                    users {
                        data {
                            name
                        }
                    }
                  }
            `}
            render={({error, props}) => {
                return <div>User: 1</div>;
            }}
        />
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

> environment.js (relay config)

```
import {
    Environment,
    Network,
    RecordSource,
    Store,
} from 'relay-runtime';

function fetchQuery(
    operation,
    variables,
) {
    return fetch('/graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: operation.text,
            variables,
        }),
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    });
}

const network = Network.create(fetchQuery);
const store = new Store(new RecordSource());

const environment = new Environment({
    network,
    store
});

export default environment;
```

Everything is from docs setup page.

Comment: Can you share the code which is causing this error? Nobody will be able to help you if all they can see is the errors in the console.

Comment: @Matt I made update.

Answer (score 1):

In `Table.js`, it seems you mixed up the syntax for importing:

```js
const environment = import('../../environment.js'); // Wrong

const environment = require('../../environment.js'); // OK
import environment from '../../environment.js'; // OK
```

Using `import('../../environment.js')` makes it a dynamic import which returns a Promise (depending on your bundler config) and is unlikely what you want.